# Firebase - "Event not sent since app measurement is disabled"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, logging

The *message* is showing only on first run of the app and is back to logging when restarting the app.
Can some one help as it has occurred for multiple times already and want to have an explanation for such behaviour.
The issue occurred is not a problem for the natural flow of the app